# Indicate top heading on table of content jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an automatic Table of Content, everything is working fine. I just need to indicated the top heading to be "bold"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var ToC =
  "<nav role='navigation' class='table-of-contents vNav'>" +
    "<ul class='vNav'>";

var newLine, el, title, link;

$(".right_section .intro_title h2, .right_section .section_one_content h2, .right_section .p_section_title h3").each(function() {

    el = $(this);
    title = el.text();
    //link = "#" + el.attr("id");
    link = "#" + el.text();

    $(this).attr('id', title);  

if ($( ".right_section .intro_title h2" )) {
    newLine =
    "<li class='vNav_heading'>" +
      "<a href='" + link + "'>" +
        title +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";    
} else {
    newLine =
    "<li class='vNav_lists'>" +
      "<a href='" + link + "'>" +
        title +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";
}

    ToC += newLine;

});

ToC +=
   "</ul>" +
  "</nav>";

$(".toc").prepend(ToC);
}); // END DOM
```

The code above adds a class (.vNav_lists) to all when it should detect (.right_section .intro_title h2) to have a class ".vNav_heading" and the rest should be ".vNav_lists"

This is the HTML markup, this is based on wordpress wysiwyg editor

```
<div class="left_section">
<div class="toc"></div>
</div>

<div class="right_section">

<div class="intro_title">
    <h2>title</h2>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>

<div class="section_one_content">
    <h2>title</h2>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>


<div class="p_section_title">
    <h3>title</h3>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>


<div>
```

This is the result, but there should be a class .vNav_heading on every top heading.

```
<div class="toc">
<nav role="navigation" class="table-of-contents vNav">
<ul class="vNav">
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">class should be .vNav_heading</a></li>
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">Text</a></li>
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">Text</a></li>
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">Text</a></li>
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">class should be .vNav_heading</a></li>
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">Text</a></li>
<li class="vNav_lists"><a href="#text">Text</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Hope its understadable, I could not explain it well

Comment: Please tell me, where's the `.right_section` markup?

Comment: where is toc class?

Comment: @bhoodream Hi, I have edited the question including the html markup

Comment: @RanjitSingh its on the .left_section of the HTML markup

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan : Check below answer, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether parent has class "intro_title"

```js
$(function(){
var ToC =
  "<nav role='navigation' class='table-of-contents vNav'>" +
    "<ul class='vNav'>";

var newLine, el, title, link;

$(".right_section .intro_title h2, .right_section .section_one_content h2, .right_section .p_section_title h3").each(function() {
    el = $(this);
    title = el.text();
    //link = "#" + el.attr("id");
    link = "#" + el.text();

    $(this).attr('id', title);  

if ($(this).closest(".intro_title").length) {
    newLine =
    "<li class='vNav_heading'>" +
      "<a href='" + link + "'>" +
        title +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";    
} else {
    newLine =
    "<li class='vNav_lists'>" +
      "<a href='" + link + "'>" +
        title +
      "</a>" +
    "</li>";
}

    ToC += newLine;

});

ToC +=
   "</ul>" +
  "</nav>";

console.log(ToC);
$(".toc").prepend(ToC);
}); // END DOM
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toc">
</div>

<div class="right_section">

<div class="intro_title">
    <h2>title</h2>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>

<div class="section_one_content">
    <h2>title</h2>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>


<div class="p_section_title">
    <h3>title</h3>
</div>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>


</div>
```